# Jacobi's theorem on sums of two squares (reference request)

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, sums-of-squares

One of Jacobi's theorems states that the number of representations of a positive integer $n$ as a sum of two squares of integers equals
$$4(d_1(n)-d_3(n)),$$
where the function $d_i$ counts the number of positive integer divisors congruent to $i \mod{4}$ of $n$.

My question is whether there are similar formulas for representations by the quadratic form $x^2+ay^2$, where $a$ is an integer other than $1$. If so, are there any references ?

Answer (score 16):

Using class field theory one can prove for every integer $n>0$ there exists a monic polynomial $f$ of degree $h(-4n)$[*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) such that for any odd integer $m$ coprime to $n$ we have the following equivalence:

$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}:(m=x^2+ny^2)\iff \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}:(f(x)\equiv 0\bmod m)\land (y^2\equiv-n\bmod m)$$

However depending on the polynomial $f$ this may or may not readily translate into a "nice" sum of Jacobi symbols, namely any expression counting solutions of this form is going to likewise need to count adjusted roots in $f$ modulo primes dividing $m$ which can then be lifted back to solutions with Henzels lemma and with the Chinese remainder theorem (even ignoring other problems). Though we can as I said find similar "nice" formulas for special cases e.g. the particular values of $n$ which force certain pdbqf's of discriminate $D=-4n$ to lie in the same genus, in particular when all the forms are in the same genus as the principal form i.e. they range over the same values in $(\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ we find that it is possible to fully characterize the primes $p$ with solutions $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ to $p=x^2+ny^2$ using only conditions on the residues of $p$ modulo fixed integers. For example we can show that:

$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}:p=x^2+6y^2\iff p\equiv 1, 7\bmod 24$$
$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}:p=x^2+21y^2\iff p\equiv 1,25,37\bmod 84$$
$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}:p=x^2+15y^2\iff p\equiv 1, 19, 31, 49\bmod 60$$

Though despite this the formula $r_2(n)=4(d_1(n)-d_3(n))$ can be generalized to counting proper representations of any integer $n$ by all the positive definite binary quadratic forms of an arbitrary fixed discriminant which can also be expressed as a similar divisor like sum involving Jacobi symbols using Dirichlet's Mass formula. While since the arbitrary representations of any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by a quadratic form are proper representations of $n/d$ coordinate wise scaled by $\sqrt{d}$ for a square $d\mid n$. We can further prove that if $r_2(n)=4(d_1(n)-d_3(n))$ is the number of integer pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ which satisfy $x^2+y^2=n$ whereas if $s(n)=|\{d\mid n:\sqrt{d}\in\mathbb{N}\}|=\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1+\lfloor v_p(n)/2\rfloor\right)$ is the number of perfect squares dividing $n$ and $\omega(n)=\sum_{p\mid n}1$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $n$ then if for every integer $m$ coprime to $n$ we define:

$$w(m)=\begin{cases}6&\text{ if }m=-3\\4&\text{ if }m=-4\\2&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

As well as the indicator function:

$$e_m(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left( \dfrac{m}{p}\right)\right)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }\exists x\in \mathbb{Z}:x^2\equiv m\bmod n\\0&\text{ if }\not\exists x\in \mathbb{Z}:x^2\equiv m\bmod n\end{cases}$$

We know if $\mathscr{F}_D$ is the set of reduced positive definite binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D$ so that by definition $h(D)=|\mathscr{F}_D|$ then for an arbitrary odd integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$ coprime to $D$ we must get that:

$$\small |\{(x,y,f)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\times\mathscr{F}_D:f(x,y)=n\land \gcd(x,y)=1\}|=w(D)\sum_{d\mid n}\left( \dfrac{D}{d}\right)=w(D)e_D(n)2^{\omega(n)}$$

$$\small\implies |\{(x,y,f)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\times\mathscr{F}_D:f(x,y)=n\}|=w(D)\sum_{d\mid n}\left( \dfrac{D}{d}\right)s(d)=w(D)e_D(n)(d_1(n)-d_3(n))$$

Thus in particular if $D=-4$ we get $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is the only reduced form of discriminant $D$ so these formula simplify to your original identity for counting the number of representations of any integer as a sum of two squares. Whereas note if $D=-28$ then $f(x,y)=x^2+7y^2$ is the only reduced form of discriminant $D$ because $h(-28)=1$ therefore for every odd integer $n>0$ not divisible by $7$, when there exists integers $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=a^2+7b^2$ then we must have by both of our previous formula that:

$$|\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:x^2+7y^2=n\land \gcd(x,y)=1\}|=2^{\omega(n)+1}$$
$$|\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:x^2+7y^2=n\}|=2(d_1(n)-d_3(n))$$

For details on reduction theory read Chapter 4 of this: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/ntii/ntii.pdf Whereas for Dirichlet's formula read page 5 of this: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/ntii/chap4.pdf For a more general approach that includes material discussed at the start, try [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118390180) by David Cox.

Comment: The last equality is not correct. Do you mean to take the sum over squarefree $d|n$ ?

Comment: @CaptainDarling Sorry, I was counting the number of proper representations. I updated it.

Answer (score 8):

The requested generalization of Jacobi's two-square theorem is a remarkably recent result: N. Bagis and M.L Glasser, [On the Number of Representations of Integers by various Quadratic and Higher Forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0466) (2015):

[image]

where $r(n)$ is Jacobi's formula for the number of representations of $n=x^2+y^2$.

---

I understand from the comments that this (general but complicated) formula is not what the OP was looking for. Berkovich and Yesilyurt in [Ramanujan's Identities and Representation of Integers by Certain Binary and Quaternary Quadratic Forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611300) (2006) give rather simple expressions for specific cases of $n=x^2+ay^2$. I reproduce below the result for $a=5$, and there are others (6,15,27,...). As explained in this [2012 MO posting,](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85741) there is no simple Jacobi-type formula that will apply to any $a$.

[image]

Comment: I don't consider this formula to be "similar" to Jacobi's formula - it is way too unwieldy. In cases that the binary form $Q = x^2 + ay^2$ has class number $1$, there should be a formula equating the theta series of $Q$ with an Eisenstein series, and be very similar to Jacobi's formula. This would occur only for $a = 1, 2, 3$ and $7$, though.

Comment: the formula immediately generalizes to more than two squares, $n=\sum_{k=1}^N A_k x_k^2$, see equation 15 of the cited paper; I find it actually more memorable than unwieldy.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy Rouse. The quoted formula (13) expresses in analytic form the simple fact that $\sum_{m+n=t}r_{A,B}(m)r_{A,B}(n)=\sum_{kA+lB=t}r(k)r(l)$. Indeed, both sides count the number of quadruples $(u,v,x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^4$ such that $Au^2+Bv^2+Ax^2+By^2=t$. In contrast, Jacobi's formula has to do with arithmetic, e.g. the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Answer (score 4):

Several examples are in [L. E. Dickson, Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007DQ0OK). Jacobi's result is Theorem 65 on page 80, several forms of class number one are in the exercises pages 80-81. Several forms with one class per genus are exercises on pages 84-88, including a few odd discriminants.

Answer (score 0):

Liouville published a series of papers concerning representations of a number by different quadratic forms. He gave many identities without proofs. Liouville's methods were reconstructed by Uspensky, see chapter "Liouville's methods" from the book *Uspensky J. V., Heaslet M. A. Elementary number theory. McGraw-Hill New York, 1939*.

One can also find another exposition of Liouville's methods in the survey *Venkov B. A. Elementary number theory. Wolters-Noordhoff Publishing, Groningen, 1970.*

Comment: There's also Number Theory in the Spirit of Liouville, by Kenneth Williams, https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/number-theory-in-the-spirit-of-liouville/51A0D57710C50412C1C535049FACCE33